# Is there a way to use zero-length arrays with 2d arrays?

Tags: arrays, c

I just discovered zero-length arrays and I'd like to use it for a 2d array, the advantage of these arrays is to avoid pointers inside a structure so we can just free the structure instead of having to free it's data, so it can better be used inside a container structure like a linked list for example without having to pass a destructor function, but the problem is I can't figure out how to use it for 2d arrays. I have a structure looking like this:

```
struct  s_arg
{
    int     argc;
    char    argv[0][0];
};
```

But the problem is: how to keep track of each member size without another array containing sizes? Is this possible to do this with no malloc for struct members ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The only reason an array can be used with no size known is because you do not need to know the size in order to access elements. Given an array `a`, `a[0]` is at the start of the array, `a[1]` is one element beyond that, and so on. The location of any element `a[i]` can be computed without knowing the size of the array.

Naturally, for an array to exist, somebody has to allocate memory for it, and so they must know the size. So the creator of an array must know its size, but the user does not need to.

GCC allows zero-length arrays as an extension so that a structure can have an array at its end, where the memory is allocated by the creator of the structure, who knows its size. Except to support old software, this extension became unnecessary once the C standard supported arrays of unknown size (declared with no size, `[]`, called *flexible array members*).

For two-dimensional arrays, the ability to use an array without knowing its size does not apply. Given a two-dimensional array of `char` named `a`, `a[i][j]` is located `j` elements after the start of `a[i]`. Each of those elements is a `char`, so calculating `j` `char` beyond `a[i]` is easy. And `a[i]` starts `i` elements after the start of `a`. But the elements of `a` are arrays of `char`. To know how big `i` elements is, **you must know the size of the element; you must know the size of the array of `char`**.

So a two-dimensional array **cannot** be used unless the size of the second dimension is known.

There are ways to use a two-dimensional array whose second-dimension size is known at run-time, including:

- Use a one-dimensional array and calculating indices into it manually, as with `a[i*size + j]`.
- Use a one-dimensional array and convert its address. For example, from some structure `s` with member `m`, `(char (*)[size]) s.m`, which can then be used as `((char (*)[size]) s.m)[i][j]`. (See other Stack Overflow questions and answers for language-lawyer issues about treating one-dimensional arrays as two-dimensional arrays.)

Also, your member name `argv` suggests you might want this structure to store command-line arguments passed as a parameter of `main`. If so, you should be mindful that the `argv` second parameter of `main` is a pointer to pointers, not a pointer to an array. The data in those strings is generally not arranged in memory for use as a two-dimensional array of `char`. You could copy the strings into a two-dimensional array, but that would generally be wasteful.

Comment: Thank you for your very well explained answer.
For the part about `argv`, I saw some people prototyping their main function like this `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` on internet, is that representation false then ?

Comment: @Fayeure: That is a correct way to declare `main`. The `argv` parameter is an array of pointers. `char *argv[]` is essentially `char *(argv[])`—`argv` is first an array, and then its elements are pointers. So the strings could be anywhere in memory—each element of the array is a pointer, and a pointer can point anywhere. They are not necessarily organized into an array. `char (*foo)[]` would be a pointer to an array of `char`. (It is not proper to declare `main` with this.) If the size were known, like `char (*foo)[1024]`, then there could be multiple arrays of `char` at the address.